# Converting double to float without relying on the FPU rounding mode

Tags: c, floating-point, bit-manipulation, ieee-754

Does anyone have handy the snippets of code to convert an IEEE 754 `double` to the immediately inferior (resp. superior) `float`, **without changing or assuming anything about the FPU's current rounding mode**?

Note: this constraint probably implies not using the FPU at all. I expect the simplest way to do it in these conditions is to read the bits of the double in a 64-bit long and to work with that.

You can assume the endianness of your choice for simplicity, and that the double in question is available through the `d` field of the union below:

```
union double_bits
{
  long i;
  double d;
};
```

I would try to do it myself but I am certain I would introduce hard-to-notice bugs for denormalized or negative numbers.

Comment: on glibc systems you find a header file ieee754.h, which defines unions for the floating point types and a bitfield structure, so you can work with the mantissa and the exponent easier, sorry but I cannot give you real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following works, but I will state my assumptions first:

- floating-point numbers are stored in IEEE-754 format on your implementation,
- No overflow,
- You have `nextafterf()` available (it's specified in C99).

Also, most likely, this method is not very efficient.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Change to non-zero for superior, otherwise inferior */
    int superior = 0;

    /* double value to convert */
    double d = 0.1;

    float f;
    double tmp = d;

    if (argc > 1)
        d = strtod(argv[1], NULL);

    /* First, get an approximation of the double value */
    f = d;

    /* Now, convert that back to double */
    tmp = f;

    /* Print the numbers. %a is C99 */
    printf("Double: %.20f (%a)\n", d, d);
    printf("Float: %.20f (%a)\n", f, f);
    printf("tmp: %.20f (%a)\n", tmp, tmp);

    if (superior) {
        /* If we wanted superior, and got a smaller value,
           get the next value */
        if (tmp < d)
            f = nextafterf(f, INFINITY);
    } else {
        if (tmp > d)
            f = nextafterf(f, -INFINITY);
    }
    printf("converted: %.20f (%a)\n", f, f);

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, it prints:

```
Double: 0.10000000000000000555 (0x1.999999999999ap-4)
Float: 0.10000000149011611938 (0x1.99999ap-4)
tmp: 0.10000000149011611938 (0x1.99999ap-4)
converted: 0.09999999403953552246 (0x1.999998p-4)
```

The idea is that I am converting the `double` value to a `float` value—this could be less than or greater than the double value depending upon the rounding mode.  When converted back to `double`, we can check if it is smaller or greater than the original value.  Then, if the value of the `float` is not in the right direction, we look at the next `float` number from the converted number in the original number's direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for this code. I was slowly becoming convinced that this was the least error-prone solution. Thanks for pointing out `nextafterf` too, that's much better than in/decrementing the bits of the `float` as if it was an `int`. To alleviate the risk of `f+1` being equal to `f`, may I write `nextafterf(f, INFINITY)` instead?

Comment: I just read the man pages, the C standard draft, and tried it out, and looks like `INFINITY` should work.

Answer (score 3):

To do this job more accurately than just re-combine mantissa and exponent bit's check this out:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23173

regards

Comment: Thanks. The `doubles2halfp` function there is as complicated as I feared, but at least it already has half the constants right, so it's a good starting point.

Comment: I would use the given code as reference and rewrite a simpler approach, using & >> follwed by or, and then check very small and very large numbers. Take the shift count and bit-position at a glance from http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html

Answer (score 2):

I posted code to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19644895/364818 and copied it below for your convenience.

```
    // d is IEEE double, but double is not natively supported.
    static float ConvertDoubleToFloat(void* d)
    {
        unsigned long long x;
        float f; // assumed to be IEEE float
        unsigned long long sign ;
        unsigned long long exponent;
        unsigned long long mantissa;

        memcpy(&x,d,8);

        // IEEE binary64 format (unsupported)
        sign     = (x >> 63) & 1; // 1
        exponent = ((x >> 52) & 0x7FF); // 11
        mantissa = (x >> 0) & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFULL; // 52
        exponent -= 1023;

        // IEEE binary32 format (supported)
        exponent += 127; // rebase
        exponent &= 0xFF;
        mantissa >>= (52-23); // left justify

        x = mantissa | (exponent << 23) | (sign << 31);
        memcpy(&f,&x,4);

        return f;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The line `exponent &= 0xFF;` means that when it would be appropriate to return `±FLT_MAX` or `±inf`, a `float` with a strange exponent is returned instead (and denormal results are off, too).

Comment: This gives incorrect results at least for denormals.